# Return Value of a shell command not getting assigned to corresponding variable and generation of "Command not found" error in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

**Code:**

```
PT = $(shell grep -oP '(?<=privilege name).*(?=/>)' $(basename $@).xml | grep -oP '(?<=").*(?=")')
echo $(PT)

ifeq($(PT),"public")
    echo "sachin has done it"
endif
```

**The above code snippet of make file gives following error:**

```
PT = platform

make[1]: PT: Command not found
```

**Issues**

`PT` should be assigned the value evaluated by `grep` command. However, it is not getting assigned and I don't know why `PT` is being treated as a command instead of a variable.

Comment: When the code was a shell-script, not a Makefile, the answer would be: Remove the spaces around the equal-sign. And use ${PT}, not $(PT) for the value of the variable. Can you check if this helps you in the Makefile?

Comment: @WalterA ..no it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this inside a recipe? Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?